# How to use a function to find the mean based upon conditions in the data

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements, mean

I'm trying to get the average of data in certain rows if certain conditions are true. For example, I'm using some car data including Make, Year, and Price.

If want to create a function so if Model = x and Year = x, find the average price from all the rows which meet these conditions.

The code below provides me with an average of all the data. If I don't include .any() I receive an error.

```
def avg_price(year, make, price):
    if (year == 2011).any() & (make == 'BMW').any():
        return np.mean(price)

avg_price(df['Year'], df['Make'], df['Price'])
```

I'll get a return of the average from the whole data frame when I want to see an average of the price data for only the rows that meet the conditions.

Comment: change & to and ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something like this should do the job:

```
def avg_price(df):
    return df [ (df.Year == 2011) & (df.make == "BMW") ].price.mean()
```

- `df [ (df.Year == 2011) & (df.make == "BMW") ]` selects the rows
- then `.price` selects the column
- and finally `.mean()` computes the means of that column over the selected rows

There are several problems with your original suggestion

- `(year == 2011).any()` will return a single boolean which is `True` if **at least one** row of the year Series contains `2011`
- but using the Series `price` , you never select the interesting rows.